# DropDownList + OnSelectedIndexChanged + AutoPostBack=False

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery, radcombobox

is it possible to force dropdown list to fire OnSelectedIndexChanged event without AutoPostBack=True?

i told that because i have some RadComboBoxes(telerik) In My Form

i am controling their focus with JQuery

such as this code when my form loads:

```
<script src="../JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('input[id$=RadcbCoNameInInsert_Input]').focus();

</script>
```

so when AutoPostBack=True  and OnSelectedIndexChanged fires after it's code telerik skin acts and finally i lost my radcombobox focus ... i mean that radcombobox skin code is against my jquery code ...

how can i force radcombo box to focus after it's postback or how can i disable it's autopostback to keep my focus on radcombobox?

(i am so amateur about jquery.)

best regards

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel, the Telerik update thing, or just a normal full-page postback?

Comment: yes , i am using an update panel around this combo box ...
i used OnSelectedIndexChanged event because of another combo box...
imagine my combo boxes like country and city choose
when user select a country form a combo box so another combo box shows citis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking `focus()` directly on a jQuery object simply invokes the `onfocus` (focus) event handler. You must invoke `focus` on the DOM elements instead, to get the browser to focus on it:

```
$('input[id$=RadcbCoNameInInsert_Input]').get().focus();
```

See http://api.jquery.com/get/ for accessing the underlying DOM elements.